# How can I show dynamic images with require() in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm fetching data from api and then i want to show images based on the symbol coming from the api data

```
{apiData ? (
    apiData.data.map((item, key) => (
      <Listing symbol={item.symbol} path={`../images/${item.symbol}.png`} />
    ))
  ) : (
    <></>
  )}
```

sending the path and the symbol to another component VVVV

```
const Listing = ({ symbol, path }) => {
  return (
    <View style={tw`flex-row justify-between p-10`}>
      <View style={tw`flex-row items-center`}>
        <Text style={tw`mr-2`}>{symbol}</Text>
        <Image source={require(path)} style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }} />
        <Text>{path}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Is there a way to do it like that or i have to use something else ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"In order for this to work, the image name in `require` has to be known statically", that's what React Native's [doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/images#static-image-resources) says. In others words, you cannot require an image in React Native with a dynamic path.

The workaround in your case is to import them statically in an object, where each key is a `symbol` and its value the `path` of its related image. Don't forget to use the correct path:

```
const images = {
  one: require("../images/imageOne.png"),
  two: require("../images/imageTwo.png"),
};
```

This way you give `Listing` only the `symbol`, and it will fetch the image from the above object:

```
const Listing = ({ symbol }) => {
  return (
    <View style={tw`flex-row justify-between p-10`}>
      <View style={tw`flex-row items-center`}>
        <Text style={tw`mr-2`}>{symbol}</Text>
        <Image source={images[symbol]} style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }} />
        <Text>{path}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```